# Flutter default font size

Tags: dart, flutter, widget

I want to have a default font size to the Text widget in Flutter.
I know that I can set default font family in theme but there is no default font size parameter.

I just wonder if my custom widget is implemented well or I did it wrong approach?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Custom Text with a default font Monospace and a default font size.
class CustomText extends Text {
  /// Custom Text Constructor extend of Text constructor.
  CustomText(this.dataCustom,
      {this.styleCustom = const TextStyle(), this.textAlignCustom})
      : super(dataCustom,
            style: styleCustom.copyWith(fontFamily: 'Monospace', fontSize: 12),
            textAlign: textAlignCustom);

  /// The text to display.
  ///
  /// This will be null if a [textSpan] is provided instead.
  final String dataCustom;

  /// If non-null, the style to use for this text.
  ///
  /// If the style's "inherit" property is true, the style will be merged with
  /// the closest enclosing [DefaultTextStyle]. Otherwise, the style will
  /// replace the closest enclosing [DefaultTextStyle].
  final TextStyle styleCustom;

  /// How the text should be aligned horizontally.
  final TextAlign textAlignCustom;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should [prefer composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51476234/subclass-a-class-that-extends-statelesswidget-or-statefulwidget-class).

```
class Mono12Text extends StatelessWidget {
  final String data;
  final TextAlign align;
  final TextStyle style;

  Mono12Text(
    this.data, {
    this.align,
    TextStyle style = const TextStyle(),
  }) : style = style.copyWith(
          fontFamily: 'Monospace',
          fontSize: 12,
        );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      data,
      textAlign: align,
      style: style,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 42):

A Flutter theme defines not one, but many default font sizes. The size used depends on the situation, e.g. a Text widget would normally use `body` style, but the same widget would use `button` style if used inside of a button.

I found two ways to increase all font sizes across a Flutter application.

### Simple solution: adjust the default theme

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(
          fontSizeFactor: 1.1,
          fontSizeDelta: 2.0,
        ),
  ),
  ...
);
```

The resulting font size is (originalSize * fontSizeFactor + fontSizeDelta). So in the example above all font sizes are increased by 10% and then additionally by 2.

### Solution with more control: define all sizes by hand

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      bodyText1: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
      bodyText2: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
      button: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
      ...  // and so on for every text style
    ),
  ),
  ...
);
```

The full list of styles can be found at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme-class.html.

Comment: This works for the light theme, but for dark theme it changes the color of the text to be unreadable. I think it's because the context theme is light by default. How can we do this for the dark theme too?

Comment: @intrepidis try to use context. First get the current theme: `final ThemeData textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;` And then modify it: `theme: ThemeData(textTheme: textTheme.copyWith(bodyText1: textTheme.bodyText1!.copyWith(fontSize: 18.0), ...)`
Does this solve the problem?

Answer (score 19):

I found a better way for default font size by overriding the material text theme.

Reference: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme-class.html

For example:
body1 is for normal Text widgets
so for the red color to all Text widgets

```
 theme: ThemeData(
        textTheme: TextTheme(body1: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.red))
      )
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: The OP's problem cries out for a theme. This should be the accepted answer. Very kind of you to give someone else the points but your own answer is better than his. Nice job. Prefer convention over configuration.

Comment: This is actually the best answer here. Exactly what was needed. I don't know why isn't it marked as accepted

Comment: This doesn't work everywhere, for example when the Text is a child inside FlatButton. Also, why does the example show how to set default background color when the question is about fontsize? You should use fontSize inside TextStyle

Comment: @RobinManoli My main point is using the Theme so background color is ok as an example

Answer (score 6):

There are several possibilities:

**1- Using the [DefaultTextStyle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DefaultTextStyle-class.html) widget** :

Just use this widget as a parent
**Example** :

```
 DefaultTextStyle(
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 17,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
       ),
      child: Text('Hello World') // I don't need to define a style for this Text widget anymore 
 ),
```

**Output :**

[image]

> I don't need to define a style for this `Text` widget anymore because it
> will default to the `DefaultTextStyle` widget style.

See also:
**[AnimatedDefaultTextStyle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedDefaultTextStyle-class.html)**, which animates changes in the text style smoothly over a given duration.
[**DefaultTextStyleTransition,**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DefaultTextStyleTransition-class.html) which takes a provided Animation to animate changes in text style smoothly over time.

**2- The use of the predefined [textTheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme-class.html)** :

In fact, all you have to do is choose a predefined textTheme and use or modify it :
Each textTheme has a predefined TextStyle that you can use directly or modify before using it.
**Here is the list of the predefined textTheme :**

```
 headline1, headline2, headline3, headline4, headline5, headline6, subtitle1, subtitle2, bodyText1, bodyText2, caption, button, overline, display4, display3, display2, display1, headline, title, subhead, subtitle, body2, body1
```

**Usage:**

```
Text('Hello World' , style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,),
```

**Output :**  [image]

*You can also change the value of this TextStyle and then reuse it.*

**Modification :**

Put it in your [MaterialApp](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html) widget .

```
theme: ThemeData(
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          headline6: TextStyle(fontSize: 15 , color: Colors.blue),
          bodyText1: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.red , color: Colors.blue) ,
          )
      ),
```

**Output :**  [image]

My code is [here](https://gist.github.com/kagouda/da35be82b9420e8363bc3108549a9778)
Learn more about TextTheme [**here**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme-class.html) .

Answer (score 5):

Expanding a bit on amorenew's answer.

You can set the fontSize inside the the MaterialApp() Widget. However note that it will not work inside all widgets, for example Flatbutton and ExpansionTile.

```
void main() {
  runApp(myApp());
}

class myApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
        title: "My Flutter App",
        theme: ThemeData(
          textTheme: TextTheme(body1: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
        ...
   );
  }
}
```

So if you want the style to be applied also to a FlatButton:

```
FlatButton(
   child:
      Text("my text",
         style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
      )
);
```

And, if you want the fontSize to be applied with other specific styles:

```
FlatButton(
   child:
      Text("my text",
         style:
            TextStyle(
               fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
               color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1.fontSize
            )
      )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `DefaultTextStyle` widget as a parent widget

> The text style to apply to descendant Text widgets which don't have an explicit style

Example on how to use:

```dart
return DefaultTextStyle(
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 42, color: Colors.blue),
              child: (...)
);
```

[More details in official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DefaultTextStyle-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

`fontSize:styleCustom.fontSize!=null ? styleCustom.fontSize:10),`## you did right except situations which you have default value like font size but you want override it ##