# How to reuse non Widget classes in Flutter?

Tags: inheritance, flutter, dart

I know we are supposed to use [composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51477727/1769177) in Flutter. And that works great when we are talking about `Widgets`.

But what am I supposed to do when a class is not a `Widget`?
For example, I want my `TextFields` in some screens to have a specific set of values in their `InputDecoration`.

Should I extend `InputDecoration`? How can I reuse this specific `InputDecoration` in many TextFields?

**EDIT:**
Following Rémi Rousselet's guidance, I extended `InputDecoration`. Here's the final result:

```
class LoginInputDecoration extends InputDecoration {
  @override
  InputBorder get errorBorder =>
      UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppColors.danger));

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get contentPadding => const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: Dimens.halfSpace,
        vertical: Dimens.singleSpace,
      );

  @override
  InputBorder get border =>
      UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppColors.primary));

  @override
  TextStyle get labelStyle =>
      TextStyle(color: AppColors.white, decorationColor: AppColors.white);

  @override
  InputBorder get enabledBorder =>
      UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppColors.primary));

  @override
  TextStyle get hintStyle =>
      TextStyle(color: AppColors.white, decorationColor: AppColors.white);

  LoginInputDecoration({String labelText}) : super(labelText: labelText);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. The "don't extend widgets" is really limited to that: widgets.

The real reason behind that "limitation" is that extending widgets do not allow to properly change the style of a widget, due to how `build` works. So extending widgets do not make sense.

But that reason does not apply to other kinds of objects. So don't worry and go ahead!

There are many examples available in Flutter already. For example, `Alignment` is a subclass of `AlignmentGeometry`.

Comment: Thanks! You are right, I managed to solve this using inheritance. I'll update my question with some code to show it.

Answer (score 0):

I have extended the Decoration class, the TextInputFormatter and TextFieldValidator class with great success for front end UI development and easy to recommend.

Decoration class to put a dotted line border around Containers.
TextInputFormatter for credit card number entry
TextFieldValidator for expiry date credit card validation.