# How to wrap a derived RaisedButton object with SizedBox in its own class?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class `MyButton` derived from `RaisedButton` as follows.

```
class MyButton extends RaisedButton {
  final double height;

  MyButton({
    String text,
    VoidCallback onPressed,
    this.height,
  }) : super(child: Text(text), onPressed: onPressed);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => SizedBox(
        height: height,
        child: this,
      );
}
```

I use it in the `main` method as follows.

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Hello World'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: MyButton(text: 'Press Me', height: 80, onPressed: () {}),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It produces a blank white page with some errors

> The following StackOverflowError was thrown building MyButton:

> [image]

## Question

How to wrap the derived `RaisedButton` with `SizedBox` in its own class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to extend RaisedButton?

Another way is to simply create a custom widget:

```
class MyButton {
  final double height;
  final String text;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
 
  MyButton({
    this.text,
    this.onPressed,
    this.height,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => SizedBox(
        height: height,
        child: RaisedButton(child: Text(text), onPressed: onPressed),
      );
}
```

Comment: I know this approach. I want to learn how to extend `RaisedButton` and do composition.

Comment: By default, you should not extend any widget, but  if you have the need and still want to use that way, try reading this post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51476234/subclass-a-class-that-extends-statelesswidget-or-statefulwidget-class

Comment: Thank  you very much. Let me wait for a couple of hours or days to accept the best answer.