# Parent widget not updating using inheritance

Tags: flutter, dart

**`ParentPage`:**

```dart
class ParentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ParentPageState createState() => ParentPageState();
}

class ParentPageState<T extends ParentPage> extends State<T> {
  int counter = 0;

  void incrementCounter() => setState(() => counter++);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Text('$counter'); // Not updating
}
```

**`ChildPage`:**

```dart
class ChildPage extends ParentPage {
  @override
  _ChildPageState createState() => _ChildPageState();
}

class _ChildPageState extends ParentPageState<ChildPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build[$counter]'); // Updates
    return Scaffold(
      body: ParentPage(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: incrementCounter,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm using `home: ChildPage()` in my `MaterialApp` widget.

**Problem**:

When I click on the FAB, it increments `counter` (which can be seen in the print statement of `_ChildPageState.build` method) but the `Text` widget in `ParentPage` stays at `0`. Why is that so?

Comment: extend parentPage why you again inside body

Comment: [Prefer composition over inheritance.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51477727/4317297)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stays at 0 because the call to `setState()` you are doing will update the state of `_ChildPageState` and not the state of your `body: ParentPage()` as it is a different instance.

Same goes for your `print('build[$counter]');` it will display the correct value because it is the `counter` variable of your `_ChildPageState` and not the one from your `ParentPage()`.

## Edit:

`_ChildPageState` by extending your `ParentPageState<ChildPage>` has a `counter` variable and an `incrementCounter()` method.

The same goes for `body: ParentPage()`, as it is a new instance of `ParentPage` it has its own `counter` and `incrementCounter()`.

By calling `incrementCounter` in your code like this:

```dart
class _ChildPageState extends ParentPageState<ChildPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ...

    return Scaffold(
      // ...
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: incrementCounter, // Here
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You are refering to the `incrementCounter` method from your `_ChildPageState` to increment the `counter` value of `_ChildPageState`. This is why `print('build[$counter]');` updates itself correctly as it is the `counter` from `_ChildPageState`.

Now for your `body: ParentPage()`, as I've said, it has its own properties and methods, which means that its method `incrementCounter` is never called and its `counter` value will never be incremented.

### Example

#### Code

```dart
class ParentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String pageId;

  const ParentPage({required this.pageId});

  @override
  ParentPageState createState() => ParentPageState();
}

class ParentPageState<T extends ParentPage> extends State<T> {
  int counter = 0;

  void incrementCounter() {
    print('Update counter from: ${widget.pageId}');
    setState(() => counter++);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Text('$counter'); // Not updating
}

class ChildPage extends ParentPage {
  const ChildPage() : super(pageId: 'ChildPage');

  @override
  _ChildPageState createState() => _ChildPageState();
}

class _ChildPageState extends ParentPageState<ChildPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build[$counter]'); // Updates
    return Scaffold(
      body: const ParentPage(pageId: 'Body Page'),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: incrementCounter,
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### Output

```sh
build[0]
Update counter from: ChildPage // First Tap
build[1]
Update counter from: ChildPage // Second Tap
build[2]
```

As you can see the `incrementCounter` from `ParentPage(pageId: 'Body Page')` is never called to increment its `counter`.

[Try the example on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=498ed35d095ac02ed7e1e3ad2315b5c3&null_safety=true)

Comment: But `setState` is used in the `ParentPage` and not in `ChildPage`.

Comment: Not exactly, your instance of `_ChildPageState` is calling `setState` but your `body: ParentPage()` is a different instance so it has its own state with its own `counter` which is not updated by `incrementCounter` because this method is part of your instance of `_ChildPageState` .

Comment: Sorry I still didn't get that. When I call `setState` in the `ParentPage`, it actually invokes the build of `ChildPage` and not the `ParentPage`? Can you also point two difference instances of `ParentPage`? Thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer with a complete example to show that the counter from your `body: ParentPage()` doesn't update itself.

Comment: Please use `@` while referring, I forgot to see your updated answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When building ChildPage you create a new instance of ParentPage.

```
body: ParentPage(),
```

That is a separate instance, so it has its own state.

It's just if you had for example 2 different Containers - you would not expect them to have the same properties just because they use the same class.

You can test it by checking the value of `counter` in the child widget.

```
class ChildPage extends ParentPage {
  @override
  _ChildPageState createState() => _ChildPageState();
}

class _ChildPageState extends ParentPageState<ChildPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build[$counter]'); // Updates
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: [ParentPage(), Text('$counter'),]),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: incrementCounter,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean I'm creating multiple instances of `ParentPage`?

Comment: @iDecode Yes, `body: ParentPage()` creates a second instance, with its own state. You could in theory replace it with `super.build(context)` but depending on what you actually want to do (other than the simple example) it may be better to extract a new Widget for the shared code, or use Provider for sharing more complex data.

Comment: What creates the first instance if `body: ParentPage()` creates the second.

Comment: @iDecode The first instance is created wherever ChildPage() is used by you, then ChildPage's build method calls constructor of ParentPage() creating the second independent widget.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with custom widget

Parent page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class ParentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ParentPageState createState() => ParentPageState();
}

class ParentPageState<T extends ParentPage> extends State<T> {
  int counter = 0;

  void incrementCounter() => setState(() => counter++);

  body() {
    return Center(child: Text('$counter'));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => body();

}
```

child page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:so_test/model/list_model.dart';
class ChildPage extends ParentPage {
  @override
  _ChildPageState createState() => _ChildPageState();
}

class _ChildPageState extends ParentPageState<ChildPage> {

  @override
  body() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: Text("$counter"),),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: incrementCounter,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So, this basically means that the BuildContext inside the build() method is actually that of it's parent. Hence, their is no need to explicitly pass it.